# Have I done something wrong in this integral?

Tags: integration, spherical-harmonics, legendre-polynomials

*I have showed most of my steps here so I hope that this is easy to follow.*

I have the integral

$$A = C\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}\int\limits_{0}^{\pi}Y^*(\theta, \phi)f(\theta,\phi)sin(\theta) d\theta d\phi$$

I have boundary conditions which say that $f(\theta, \phi) = u_0$ for the range $[0 \le \theta < \pi/2]$ and $f(\theta, \phi) = 0$ for the range $[\pi/2 \le \theta \le \pi]$.

$Y^*(\theta, \phi)$ is the spherical harmonic in which $m=0$, thus there is no $\phi$ dependence, such that:

$$Y^*(\theta, \phi) = Y(\theta, \phi) = \sqrt{\frac{(2l + 1)}{4\pi}} P_l(cos\theta)$$

where $P_l(cos\theta)$ is the Legendre polynomial.

Thus the integral becomes

$$A = u_0C\sqrt{\frac{(2l + 1)}{4\pi}}\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}\int\limits_{0}^{\pi} P_l(cos(\theta))sin(\theta) d\theta d\phi$$

Let $x = cos(\theta)$ so that $d\theta = -\frac{dx}{sin(\theta)}$ which reduces the integral to

$$A = u_0C\sqrt{\frac{(2l + 1)}{4\pi}}\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}\int\limits_{0}^{1} P_l(x) dx d\phi$$
*(Notice that I have changed the limits for $x$ and then swapped them so that the negative sign would dissapear)*

Finally, we can leave the Legendre polynomial integral as it is (we want it in this form), and only perform the integral over $\phi$ (which gives $2\pi$), leaving us with:

$$A = 2\pi u_0C\sqrt{\frac{(2l + 1)}{4\pi}}\int\limits_{0}^{1} P_l(x) dx $$
Is this correct? I got confused because at the start the functions depend on $\phi$ but I guess once applying the boundary conditions the dependence is removed, thus allowing me to do it this way?

Comment: You have to integrate over $[0 \le \theta < \pi]$ but you only have $f(\theta,\phi)$ for $[0 \le \theta < \pi/2]$?

Comment: @Juris As I said, when you use the substitution $\cos(\theta) = x$, the limits change such that $cos(0) = 1$ and $cos(\pi/2) = 0$. The lower limit is 1, the upper is 0. Swapping them gives a minus sign which cancels the minus sign from doing the substitution for $d\theta$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your function does not depend on $\phi$ for the very beginning therefore it is correct that you have no dependancy in the end :)

Some more details that I noticed:

"$f(\theta, \phi) = u_0$ for the range $[0 \le \theta < \pi/2]$" <- but you have to integrate over range $[0 \le \theta < \pi]$, what's the $f(\theta, \phi)$ for $[\pi/2 \le \theta < \pi]$?

When you do $x = cos(\theta)$, the limits should change to $-1$ and $1$ not $0$ and $1$.

I supopse the limits are wrong and you actually have to integrate over $[0 \le \theta < \pi/2]$...?

Comment: I am given a boundary condition for the extra integral but the function $f(\theta, \phi)$ is actually equal to $0$ so I did not include it :) Also, I don't understand why it would be -1 and 1 ?

Comment: PS: I added the extra BCs in the question just to be explicit :)

Comment: @PPG Alright, now your calculations seem all fine to me.